# Groovy How can i replace COMMA with ','

Tags: groovy

I've this string
('ROLE_Failed,ROLE_USER')
How can i replace COMMA with **','**
so that the output be like 
**('ROLE_Failed','ROLE_USER')**

Update:
**groovy('authentication.principal.roles.roleName.join(", ")')**
Above statement returns me: *('ROLE_Failed,ROLE_USER')*
How can I updated the above statement so that it returns me
*('ROLE_Failed','ROLE_USER')*

I've tried what is suggested, below is my statement:
**groovy('authentication.principal.roles.roleName.join(", ").replace(',',"','")')**

Exception I'm getting:
 **unexpected token:  @ line 1, column 60.
   s.roleName.join(", ").replace(**

Comment: This post is not related to JasperReports Server. It is just about groovy experience: `How can i replace COMMA with ','`

Comment: @AlexK I'm a Jasper guy and have no idea about groovy need inputs in solving this?

Answer (score 3):

```
​"('ROLE_Failed,ROLE_USER')".replace(",", "','")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I'm getting following exception: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException. Do we've to use any escape sequence?

Comment: Jeremies Code works like above. If you have compilation errors, they are not from this line.

Comment: @GeekExplorer The above line worked for me. Can you please post the whole code so that we can find the issue?

Comment: Hi @dilipyadav yeah it is working, but in my case it's not working. I've updated the question please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Jeremie B is correct. However, I think you may still meet exception from copy-and-paste issue.

Consider the below code:
[image: Example of problem code]

As you can see, the "same" code may produce different results: the first test succeeded, the second didn't. If I retype the code manually, the issue will not occur.

Presumably this error occurs when you copy the code from outside source, some character-converting issue may happens under the hood, that cause your character " or ' still look the same, but is inherently another symbol. That's why the compiler complains.

Code in text for your reference (not sure problem can be reproduced by copying this text, as SO may standardize the post encoding)

```
def str = "('ROLE_Failed,ROLE_USER')"
println str
def a = str.replace(',',"','")
println a
//-------------------------------------
def str2 = "('ROLE_Failed,ROLE_USER')"
println str2
def ab = str2.replace(',',"','")​​​​​​​​
println ab
```

**EDIT after question updated:**

The code:

> I've tried what is suggested, below is my statement:
>   groovy('authentication.principal.roles.roleName.join(",
>   ").replace(',',"','")')

If I see it correctly, **there's a blank space right after the comma**.
So the code need to be written:

```
authentication.principal.roles.roleName.join(", ").replace(', ',"','")
```

Comment: After testing: copy the code in this answer can produce this interesting result, just like in the picture

Comment: @Long your snippet is working, but in my case its not working. I've updated the question please look into it.

Comment: Hi @GeekExplorer, please check my edit... There's a blank space after your comma?

Comment: yes there's a blank space after comma. I tried it I'm getting error at **replace(", ","** .I suspect may be we've to use escape characters. I tried / but didn't worked

Comment: I saw in the question comment, that you're running on Jasper Server? Is there any document about how to call groovy script inside your environment? (it may be different to the native Groovy). Sorry that I could not be much help, I cannot reproduce your case in my environment

Comment: btw, you may want to change your question title to "How to do X in Y environment..." The way your question present itself now looks like a trivial question, but likely it isn't

Comment: Not much documentation from Jasper, I'm very thankful that you helped me till here, at least you understood that I'm not a Groovy guy. Thank you so much mate :) I'll check that.

Comment: Hey, I got this syntax can you update accordingly:**Transaction100_MyTable.RoleName in ( groovy('authentication.principal.roles.roleName.split(",")
                                                      .collect{"''" + roleName + "''"}
                                                      .join(",")
                                                      .replaceFirst("^''","")
                                                      .replaceFirst("''\$","")'
                                      )
                              )**